# Два div по центру одного flex?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Как выравнивать оба блока `child` по центру родительского? Без `position: absolute;` с помощью flex-атрибутов это возможно?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.child1 {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  transition: ease 5s;
}
.child2 {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете рассказать что именно у вас не получается? В исполняемом я вижу что оба `div` по центру.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нужно что бы зеленый был по центру красного. при том, что зеленый в html нельзя вложить в красный

Comment: За такими условиями без абсолюта ни как. У вас они должны бить на разных слоях разнесены.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я так и написал, просто плохо разбираюсь во всех атрибутах flex-box поэтому решил спросить, может можно как-то им это реализовать без абсолюта

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете получить данное положение через отрицательные `margin`. При этом помните, что для элементов flex можно задавать `z-index`, которые будут работать даже без абсолютного позиционирования, определяя кто на кого "залазит". Присваиваете `child2` `margin-top: -30vh` — это половина высоты `.child1` (`25vh`) + половина высоты `child2` (`5vh`). Далее чтобы из-за этого границы `parent` не вылезли выше добавляете

```
.parent:after {
  /* половина высоты .child1 - половина высоты .child2 */
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  content: "";
}
```

Весь код:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  transition: ease 5s;
}

.child2 {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -30vh;
}

.parent:after {
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

К `.parent` добавьте свойства `align-items: center;` и justify-content: `center;`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.child1 {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  transition: ease 5s;
}
.child2 {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: видимо нет, прикрепил к вопросу скрин как должно выглядеть

Comment: @nueq Сейчас подумаю еще.

Comment: @nueq обновил пример.